# How to distinguish compiler-inferred implicit conversion from explicitly invoked one?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-2.10, scala-macros

Let's imagine passing these two equivalent expressions to a Scala macro:

- with compiler-inferred implicit conversion: `1+"foo"`
- with explicitly invoked implicit conversion: `any2stringadd(1)+"foo"`

Is there a way to distinguish between these two inside the macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `1 + "foo"` case is going to be tricky because there isn't actually any implicit conversion happening there: `Int` itself [really, truly does have this `+` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L49) ([unfortunately](https://twitter.com/puffnfresh/status/287444061034520576)).

So you're out of luck if that's your use case, but it is possible to do what you're describing more generally. I'll assume the following setup in my examples below:

```
case class Foo(i: Int)
case class Bar(s: String)
implicit def foo2bar(foo: Foo) = Bar(foo.i.toString)
```

First for the elegant approach:

```
object ConversionDetector {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def sniff[A](tree: _): Boolean = macro sniff_impl[A]
  def sniff_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(tree: c.Tree) = {
    // First we confirm that the code typechecks at all:
    c.typeCheck(tree, c.universe.weakTypeOf[A])

    // Now we try it without views:
    c.literal(
      c.typeCheck(tree, c.universe.weakTypeOf[A], true, true, false).isEmpty
    )
  }
}
```

Which works as desired:

```
scala> ConversionDetector.sniff[Bar](Foo(42))
res1: Boolean = true

scala> ConversionDetector.sniff[Bar](foo2bar(Foo(42)))
res2: Boolean = false
```

Unfortunately this requires untyped macros, which are currently only available in [Macro Paradise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/untypedmacros.html).

You can get what you want with plain old `def` macros in 2.10, but it's a bit of a hack:

```
object ConversionDetector {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def sniff[A](a: A) = macro sniff_impl[A]
  def sniff_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(a: c.Expr[A]) = {
    import c.universe._

    c.literal(
      a.tree.exists {
        case app @ Apply(fun, _) => app.pos.column == fun.pos.column
        case _ => false
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And again:

```
scala> ConversionDetector.sniff[Bar](Foo(42))
res1: Boolean = true

scala> ConversionDetector.sniff[Bar](foo2bar(Foo(42)))
res2: Boolean = false
```

The trick is to look for places where we see function application in our abstract syntax tree, and then to check whether the positions of the `Apply` node and its `fun` child have the same column, which indicates that the method call isn't explicitly present in the source.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't know that `Int` has a method `+` that accepts `String` but I meant the general case anyway. I was thinking about using `Position`s too, but this indeed smells a bit 'hacky'. I think it would be cool if `Tree`s had some flag that would say "this tree was automatically inferred by compiler".

Comment: I just found a [comment](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Trees.scala#L431) in `scala-reflect` sources that talks about some potential flag on `Apply` AST that will indicate implicit conversion. And it looks like that now there is a separate class to indicate this (it is internal, unfortunately).

Comment: Unfortunately using the `Position` trick will mean your code blows up when used in the REPL. @ghik, I think you're on the right track with your last comment, which @EugeneBurmako's answer elaborates on.

Answer (score 2):

That's a hack, but it might help you:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import language.experimental.macros

object Macros {
  def impl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int]) = {
    import c.universe._
    val hasInferredImplicitArgs = x.tree.isInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Trees#ApplyToImplicitArgs]
    val isAnImplicitConversion = x.tree.isInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Trees#ApplyImplicitView]
    println(s"x = ${x.tree}, args = $hasInferredImplicitArgs, view = $isAnImplicitConversion")
    c.literalUnit
  }

  def foo(x: Int) = macro impl
}

import language.implicitConversions
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Test extends App {
  def bar[T: ClassTag](x: T) = x
  implicit def foo(x: String): Int = augmentString(x).toInt
  Macros.foo(2)
  Macros.foo(bar(2))
  Macros.foo("2")
}

08:30 ~/Projects/210x/sandbox (2.10.x)$ ss
x = 2, args = false, view = false
x = Test.this.bar[Int](2)(ClassTag.Int), args = true, view = false
x = Test.this.foo("2"), args = false, view = true
```