# How to develop macro to short-circuit null?

Tags: scala, macros

In Scala, if I have

```
hub = myBicycle.getFrontWheel.getHub()
```

and it is possible the front wheel is missing, i.e. `myBicycle.getFrontWheel() == null`, and I just want `hub` to be assigned `null` in such a case, what is the most concise way to express that?

I'm currently having to do

```
hub = if (myBicycle.getFrontWheel() == null) null else myBicycle.getFrontWheel.getHub()
```

and it gets worse when the chain of accessors is even longer.

Not being familiar with Scala macros, I'm wondering if it's possible to write a Scala macro that somehow captures the method name and applies it only if the object reference is non-null?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I have recently written exactly such a macro, inspired by [a question about null-safe dereferences in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163393/best-scala-imitation-of-groovys-safe-dereference-operator). By the way, this is very similar question to this one and contains a long discussion about what you can do to achieve this, including usage of `Option`, fancy ways of catching NPEs and such.

A few remarks about macro that I have written (source included below):

- It returns an `Option`, and it will be `None` when at some point there was a null dereference.
- It translates every member access by dot into a null-guarded access using if-else that returns `None` when the prefix is `null`.
- It got a little more complicated that I imagined it to be...
- There are some corner cases for which it will not work, the one I know about is when using `getClass` method - which is handled specially by the compiler in regards of its return type.
- There is a potential inconsistency regarding implicit conversions. Imagine that you have an expression `a.b` and `b` is reached through an implicit conversion, so effectively, this expression is something like `conv(a).b`. Now, the question arises: Should we check if `a` is `null` or `conv(a)` is `null` or both? Currently, my macro checks only if `a` is `null` as it seemed a little more natural to me, but this may not be desired behaviour in some cases. Also, detection of an implicit conversion in my macro is a little hack, described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508660/how-to-distinguish-compiler-inferred-implicit-conversion-from-explicitly-invoked).

The macro:

```
def withNullGuards[T](expr: T): Option[T] = macro withNullGuards_impl[T]

def withNullGuards_impl[T](c: Context)(expr: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[Option[T]] = {
  import c.universe._

  def eqOp = newTermName("==").encodedName
  def nullTree = c.literalNull.tree
  def noneTree = reify(None).tree
  def someApplyTree = Select(reify(Some).tree, newTermName("apply"))

  def wrapInSome(tree: Tree) = Apply(someApplyTree, List(tree))

  def canBeNull(tree: Tree) = {
    val sym = tree.symbol
    val tpe = tree.tpe

    sym != null &&
      !sym.isModule && !sym.isModuleClass &&
      !sym.isPackage && !sym.isPackageClass &&
      !(tpe <:< typeOf[AnyVal])
  }

  def isInferredImplicitConversion(apply: Tree, fun: Tree, arg: Tree) =
    fun.symbol.isImplicit && (!apply.pos.isDefined || apply.pos == arg.pos)

  def nullGuarded(originalPrefix: Tree, prefixTree: Tree, whenNonNull: Tree => Tree): Tree =
    if (canBeNull(originalPrefix)) {
      val prefixVal = c.fresh()
      Block(
        ValDef(Modifiers(), prefixVal, TypeTree(null), prefixTree),
        If(
          Apply(Select(Ident(prefixVal), eqOp), List(nullTree)),
          noneTree,
          whenNonNull(Ident(prefixVal))
        )
      )
    } else whenNonNull(prefixTree)

  def addNullGuards(tree: Tree, whenNonNull: Tree => Tree): Tree = tree match {
    case Select(qualifier, name) =>
      addNullGuards(qualifier, guardedQualifier =>
        nullGuarded(qualifier, guardedQualifier, prefix => whenNonNull(Select(prefix, name))))
    case Apply(fun, List(arg)) if (isInferredImplicitConversion(tree, fun, arg)) =>
      addNullGuards(arg, guardedArg =>
        nullGuarded(arg, guardedArg, prefix => whenNonNull(Apply(fun, List(prefix)))))
    case Apply(Select(qualifier, name), args) =>
      addNullGuards(qualifier, guardedQualifier =>
        nullGuarded(qualifier, guardedQualifier, prefix => whenNonNull(Apply(Select(prefix, name), args))))
    case Apply(fun, args) =>
      addNullGuards(fun, guardedFun => whenNonNull(Apply(guardedFun, args)))
    case _ => whenNonNull(tree)
  }

  c.Expr[Option[T]](addNullGuards(expr.tree, tree => wrapInSome(tree)))
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's an additional piece of code that makes the syntax nicer:

```
def any2question_impl[T, R >: T](c: Context {type PrefixType = any2question[T]})(default: c.Expr[R]): c.Expr[R] = {
  import c.universe._

  val Apply(_, List(prefix)) = c.prefix.tree
  val nullGuardedPrefix = withNullGuards_impl(c)(c.Expr[T](prefix))
  reify {
    nullGuardedPrefix.splice.getOrElse(default.splice)
  }
}

implicit class any2question[T](any: T) {
  def ?[R >: T](default: R): R = macro any2question_impl[T, R]
}
```

Finally, you can have code like this:

```
val str1: String = "hovercraftfullofeels"
val result1 = str1.substring(3).toUpperCase ? "THERE WAS NULL"
println(result1) // prints "ERCRAFTFULLOFEELS"

val str2: String = null
val result2 = str2.substring(3).toUpperCase ? "THERE WAS NULL"
println(result2) // prints "THERE WAS NULL"
```

Comment: You don't have a null-safe "if" lying around? So when it evaluates to null it's like false? Then one could just write if (some.stuff.is sane()) and don't worry if some.stuff evaluates to null or not, it would just be short-cut'ed to "false"

Comment: @andreak I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. The macro works roughly by translating every `prefix.member` into `{val p = prefix; if(p != null) Some(p.member) else None}`.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're having to interoperate with fixed Java code, you should use `Option` instead of `null`; thus `getFrontWheel()` would return `Option[Wheel]`, then you can use `map`/`flatMap` to go down the chain:

```
val hub:Option[Hub] = myBicycle.getFrontWheel().flatMap(wheel => wheel.getHub())
val spoke:Option[Spoke] = myBicycle.getFrontWheel().flatMap(wheel => wheel.getHub().map(hub => hub.getSpoke()))
```

(assumes `hub.getSpoke()` returns `Spoke`, not `Option[Spoke]`)

The last example can be rewritten as

```
val spoke:Option[Spoke] =
  for (wheel <- myBicycle.getFrontWheel();
       hub <- wheel.getHub())
  yield hub.getSpoke()
```

If you really must deal with `null` you can easily convert the result by wrapping in `Option`:

```
val wheel:Option[Wheel] = Option(myBicycle.getFrontWheel())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
def nil[B >: Null] (fun : => B) : B = {
  try fun
  catch {case e : NullPointerException => null}
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
val hub = nil(myBicycle.getFrontWheel.getHub)
```

It will affect null exceptions from nested calls too though. And if you want to write it the way you previously mentioned, do it at least like this:

```
val hub = Option(myBicycle.getFrontWheel()).map(_.getHub).getOrElse(null)
```