# Improve Groovy Safe Dereference operator in Scala

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, dereference

In response to my question [How to develop macro to short-circuit null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775699) someone pointed me to an earlier long thread with many answers, the most compelling of which to was https://stackoverflow.com/a/5569905 .  But it doesn't quite work with Scala AnyVal "primitives" like Int:

```
object TestOp {

  class SafeDereference[A](obj: A) {
    def ?[B >: Null](function: A => B): B = if (obj == null) null else function(obj)
  }
  implicit def safeDereference[A](obj: A) = new SafeDereference(obj)

  class C { 
    def getValue: Int = 0                     
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c = new C
    val x:Int = c ? (_.getValue)
  }
}
```

gives a compilation error of:

```
[error] TestOp.scala:14: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Any
[error]  required: Int
[error]     val x:Int = c ? (_.getValue)
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/home/mmalak/streaming-demo/}default-ae36bd/compile:compile: Compilation failed
```

A workaround is to replace val x:Int with val x:java.lang.Integer, and that will compile.  Is there a way to improve SafeDereference above so that val x:Int is allowed?

**Additional information**

The following produces the desired output.  The question now becomes how to move the typecasts into SafeDereference, and how to handle all the other Scala "primitives" (Boolean etc).

```
object TestOp {

  class SafeDereference[A](obj: A) {
    def ?[B >: Null](function: A => B): B = if (obj == null) null else function(obj)
  }
  implicit def safeDereference[A](obj: A) = new SafeDereference(obj)

  class C { 
    def getValue: Int = 0                     
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c:C = null
    val x = (c ? (_.getValue)).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer].asInstanceOf[Int]
    println("x="+x)
  }
}
```

outputs, as desired:

```
x=0
```

Comment: Int is not a reference type per se (that's why it inherits from AnyVal not AnyRef) and normally is not nullable

Comment: What should `c ? (_.getValue)` return if `c == null`?

Comment: "Scala `AnyRef` primitive" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Randall: typo, corrected to AnyVal in my original question.

Comment: EECOLOR: Added second example to original question, showing desired output for c == null, and a long (undesired) way to achieve it.

Comment: @MichaelMalak, I figured that's what you wanted. My answer provides a solution to that and (potentially) any other types that you want to use.

Comment: @MichaelMalak, I have added an example for `Boolean` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. The `Zero` trait allows you to determine the zero value for any object that is not `nullable`. In this case I added one for `Numeric` types:

```
object TestOp {

  trait Zero[T] {
    def apply(): T
  }

  object Zero {
    implicit def zeroNull[B >: Null] =
      new Zero[B] { def apply = null }

    implicit def zeroNumeric[B: Numeric] =
      new Zero[B] { def apply = implicitly[Numeric[B]].zero }
  }

  implicit class SafeDereference[A](obj: A) {
    def ?[B](function: A => B)(implicit zero: Zero[B]): B =
      if (obj == null) zero() else function(obj)
  }

  class C {
    def getValue: Int = 0
    def getSomething: C = new C
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c = new C
    val x = c ? (_.getValue)
    val y = c ? (_.getSomething)
  }
}
```

### Edit

For `Boolean` you would add something like this:

```
implicit def zeroBoolean[B >: Boolean] =
  new Zero[B] { def apply = false }
```

Comment: Great!  How to also default Boolean to false?